# How to do A/B testing with Cloudflare workers

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm looking for an example of what these two lines of code look like in a functioning A/B testing worker. From https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/ab-testing

```js
const TEST_RESPONSE = new Response("Test group") // e.g. await fetch("/test/sompath", request)
const CONTROL_RESPONSE = new Response("Control group") // e.g. await fetch("/control/sompath", request)
```

I used the examples, subsituting the paths I’m using, and got a syntax error saying await can only be used in async. So I changed the function to async function handleRequest(request) and got a 500 error.

What should these two lines look like for the code to work?

Answer (score 1):

Working example

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFun);



async function myFun() {
  const isTest = Math.random() > 0.5 //here you place your condition
  const res = isTest ? await fetch1() : await fetch1() //here you should have different fetches for A and B
  console.log(res)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.message;
}

async function fetch1() {
  //I took the link from some other SO answer as I was running into CORS problems with e.g. google.com
  return fetch("https://currency-converter5.p.rapidapi.com/currency/list?format=json", {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "currency-converter5.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "**redacted**"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">button</button>
<div id="demo">demo</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've worked on this a bit and this worker below seems to fulfill your requirements:

```js
async function handleRequest(request) {
  const NAME = "experiment-0";
  try {
    // The Responses below are placeholders. You can set up a custom path for each test (e.g. /control/somepath ).
    const TEST_RESPONSE = await fetch(
      "https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg",
      request
    );
    const CONTROL_RESPONSE = await fetch(
      "https://httpbin.org/image/png",
      request
    );

    // Determine which group this requester is in.
    const cookie = request.headers.get("cookie");
    if (cookie && cookie.includes(`${NAME}=control`)) {
      return CONTROL_RESPONSE;
    } else if (cookie && cookie.includes(`${NAME}=test`)) {
      return TEST_RESPONSE;
    } else {
      // If there is no cookie, this is a new client. Choose a group and set the cookie.
      const group = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "test" : "control"; // 50/50 split
      const response = group === "control" ? CONTROL_RESPONSE : TEST_RESPONSE;
      return new Response(response.body, {
        status: response.status,
        headers: {
          ...response.headers,
          "Set-Cookie": `${NAME}=${group}; path=/`,
        },
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    var response = [`internal server error: ${e.message}`];
    if (e.stack) {
      response.push(e.stack);
    }
    return new Response(response.join("\n"), {
      status: 500,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "text/plain",
      },
    });
  }
}

addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});
```

There are some issues with the snippet once you uncomment the `fetch()` parts:

- Yes, the function needs to be `async` in order to use `await` keyword, so I added that.
- Additionally, I think the 500 error you were seeing was also due to a bug in the snippet: You'll notice I form a `new Response` instead of modifying the one that was chosen from the ternary expression. This is because responses are **immutable** in the workers runtime, so adding headers to an already instantiated response will result in an error. Therefore, you can just create an entirely new `Response` with all the bits from the original one and it seems to work.
- Also, in order to gain insight into errors in a worker, always a good idea to add the `try`/`catch` and render those errors in the worker response.

To get yours working on this, just replace the `httpbin.org` urls with whatever you need to A/B test.